# Approve button appears on question which I have already reviewed. Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

While reviewing questions for suggested edits I approved a question from the direct question source and also I was able to approve the same question in the review queue. Is this a bug in system?

Steps to reproduce :

1. choose the question from review queue ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/921120/cloned-disk-isnt-bootable))
2. navigate to the question of the source
3. click on `edit(1)` from the question and approve the edit
4. Now go back to the review queue of the same [question](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/383619)
5. click on "approve" and you have approved the question for a second time

Is this a bug in a system? Per the system it should not allow user to approve for second time. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: Who exactly did two reviews in your sample question?

Comment: myself@PatrickHofman

Comment: So does the review actually show *two approvals* or did you just still see the 'Approve' button? You may have that button but that doesn't mean the system will record two votes.

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303: I don't see your username in the review.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

While the review dialog allows you to press 'Approve', it doesn't actually count if you approved it already using the question page. It just skips the item, and uses the first decision you made.

I have tested your scenario and the outcome can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8249599)

Comment: if i click on approve for second time,atleast there should be some option stating that you have already reviewed it

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303: No, it just ignores it. It doesn't matter you clicked twice.